# GUI, cross-platform, C# and OpenGL. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, opengl, user-interface, cross-platform, desktop

Is it possible to make a desktop application, which would be cross-platform (Windows, Linux and perhaps Mac), which would feature a GUI (standard stuff, textboxes, buttons and such), it would be written in C#, and would have a 3D viewer / window, which would be driven through OpenGL?

I'm accustomed to the WPF/Xaml environment when it comes to creating a GUI, mostly in Visual Studio, coupled with XNA for 3D elements, but I need it to be OpenGL now, mostly because I need it to be cross-platform (I am going to be loading proprietary custom object formats, so I don't really have a need for third-party libraires).

Is there a way to do the above? And if there is, how and which tools would be necessary? (IDE examples, tutorials...)

EDIT: I am currently looking at a combination of [GtkGlAreaSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkGlAreaSharp), [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) and [Tao](https://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/) as a wrapper. I'm looking forward to possibly simpler suggestions.

Comment: cross-platform C# isn't quite possible (unless you reach for the Wine)

Comment: Have you already checked out what MonoDevelop offers? http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: @Teknikaali I have taken a look at both mono and gtk#, and I couldn't really discern if what I was asking was possible. The C# part was great, but I'm not sure how to bring it together with OpenGL, and I didn't find any particularly helpful resources online, hence this question.

Comment: @rene programmers.se is a site unfamiliar to me, and more importantly in Swedish, and translated content could be unreliable. Did you mean programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @MarkoMadic Yes I did mean http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ sorry about the confusion. But it is always good to check where the swedes are up to...

Comment: You could consider GtkSharp. If you want "standard" UI elements you are going to have to use a framework that does NOT use the platform's native controls. Gtk does a good job of NOT using them, so the UI will look pretty consistent across all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono is the way to go then. Specifically, have a look at the Tao Framework http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/

Comment: I've seen a lot of Tao-made pieces of software out there, which were used purely as a display layer. Is there something worthy of mention, with a GUI like I described?